# What path should train tracks follow to appear parallel all the way to the horizon?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Imagine standing between the rails on a train track and looking out towards the horizon. The rails are parallel, but they appear to converge as they recede into the distance. **Is there any curve that the two rails could follow such that they appear parallel out to the horizon instead of appearing to converge?**

My best guess would be that to appear parallel the apparent distance between the curves must remain constant. For that to be the case, it seems like two diverging lines would suffice since the length of the horizon ought to grow linearly with distance from the observer - meaning the space between the lines ought to grow linearly as well to maintain a constant proportion of the horizon.

I suppose that this should be a fairly simple problem in projective geometry, but I don't know the first thing about that subject and couldn't find any discussions of this problem elsewhere online.

Comment: Projections map lines to lines, so your guess about the form of the curve is correct.

Comment: @Amd I also thought this, so answer should be lines?

Comment: @KingTut That’s right. Working out what those lines ought to be is a nice exercise.

Comment: The lines start directly below the observer and diverge from there, right?

Comment: @Rahul I don't think it should matter. My feeling is that the thing that matters most is that you know the arclength subtended at a certain known distance from where you stand. The reason being that if the lines appear parallel from where you are standing, they ought to appear parallel from ten paces forward - only a little farther apart. Although, my intuition may be mistaken.

Comment: You do realize that the observer must have its eyball in one specific point only and that only at that point will they appear parallel?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that something looks of the same size to you if it takes up the same angle of view, the tracks should start at your locations and go radially outwards in straight lines. The angle between them determines the aparent distance.

[image]

---

If we assume that your eye is positioned some distance above the ground, then its a bit more complicated. Your region of "constant angle of view" can be described by a cone. The tracks then have to go along the intersection of this view-cone and the ground plane. This is a conic section, in our case it gives a *hyperbola*.

[image]

The arrow points in the direction of view.

---

If we keep the assumption that "same apparent size" = "same angle of view", then this implies that the problem can have no translational symmetry, because every view point and view direction needs a different cone to intersect with the ground.

Comment: Well, this is where I was when I posted the question, but this construction has issues. First, while it is reasonable, it's not obvious to me that this assumption is actually correct (which is why I mention it specifically in the question). Additionally, it's unphysical since your eye would have to be at the vertex of the lines. On top of that, if you step forward on the tracks, then they stop subtending the same angle and appear to converge - which is a confusing and counter-intuitive result.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe this is argument **is** rigorous and correct, but then the answer would have to be a hyperbola, right? One where your eye is at the center, and the tracks from your diagram become the asymptotes.

Comment: @Geoffrey I did not know that one of your assumptions was that the eye is some distance above the ground. If I take this into acccount then I get hyperbolas too (I can extend by answer to contain this). The point of view from which you observe the effect of equidistant tracks is a single point. In the moment you move, the effect vanishes. I think there is less you can do about this.

Comment: Whether the point of observation is above the plane or in the plane doesn't really matter to me - I think either condition is interesting. My main concern's are (a) if you are in the plane then you wouldn't see anything if there was a point on your eye (but that would be solved by just cutting off some part of the track) and (b) I don't understand why only one point should be privileged. It seems like the problem should have some degree of symmetry for translations along the central axis.

Comment: Actually, as I think about it some more, I think that stepping forward on the track might actually appear to keep the tracks asymptotically parallel even if the subtended angle initial decreases somewhat. I'll need to work it out by hand when I have some time.

Comment: I don’t believe that the hyperbola you have is correct. A perspective projection of that hyperbola onto a plane perpendicular to the ground is still going to be a hyperbola. For a pair of world curves to appear parallel, they must lie on a pair of planes through the view point. The traces of those curves on the ground plane are its intersections with that pair of planes, which is again a pair of intersecting lines.

Comment: @amd we seem to disagree about how to model „apparently parallel“. Can you give a reason for this: „For a pair of world curves to be [i think you mean *appear*] parallel, they must lie on a pair of planes through the view point.“. I have a hard time understanding your comment from this sentence on.

Comment: I did write *appear*. Anyway, the image we’re trying to create is a pair of parallel lines on some plane orthogonal to the camera’s line of sight. Points on either of these lines back-project to rays that lie on a plane that contains the line and camera location. Whatever curves produce the desired image must therefore lie on these two planes. If those curves are further constrained to be coplanar, then the only possibility is a pair of intersecting lines, regardless of camera position. Granted, this is a degenerate hyperbola, but not the one you’ve drawn.

Comment: With the camera centered above the hyperbola’s center and camera axis parallel to the hyperbola’s plane as you’ve illustrated, its perspective projection onto a view plane orthogonal to this axis is another hyperbola, not a pair of parallel lines. The hyperbola doesn’t produce the desired image.

Comment: @amd I am sorry for misquoting you! And I see were our disagreement is based on. I understand what plane you are talking about. I know such planes from working in computer graphics. The image you are creating is the one rendered on a screen by e.g. OpenGL or DirectX. However, there is another way to talk about „what we see“. Actually, parallel lines rendered on a screen do not look equidistant to an observer in front of it. They suffer from the same "convergence in the distance"-effect (think about a very large screen). I think a hyperbola on a screen look equidistant by my post's reasoning.

Comment: Right. That made the difference click for me. Projecting onto a sphere and insisting that the angle or the projections remains constant indeed yields a hyperbola. Indeed, for a viewer at the origin looking up the $z$-axis and the $y=-1$ ground plane in my answer, the hyperbola turns out to be $1-x^2+z^2=(1+x^2+z^2)\cos\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends critically on what you mean by “appear parallel.” If it’s that the visual angle made by the two rails is constant, then we’re basically talking about a projection onto a sphere, in which case the rails are hyperbolic as explained in [M. Winter’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2639922/265466). On the other hand, if you mean that the lines are parallel on a perspective projection such as the image created by the usual pinhole camera model, then the rails are a pair of intersecting straight lines, as I’ll explain below.

Projective transformations map straight lines to straight lines, so your guess is correct, assuming that the rails lie on a common world plane—the ground plane. The projection induces a homography $\mathtt H$ between the ground and image planes. If a line on the ground plane is represented by the homogeneous vector $\mathbf l$, then its image is the line $\mathbf l'=\mathtt H^{-T}\mathbf l$, and so the line on the ground plane that corresponds to a line $\mathbf l'$ in the image is $\mathtt H^T\mathbf l'$.

Actually, a line in the image back-projects to a *plane* in the world. If the curves in the world that project onto a pair of parallel lines in the image aren’t constrained to be coplanar, then they must nevertheless lie on the two planes that correspond to the image lines. If the projection matrix is $\mathtt P$, then the plane that corresponds to a line $\mathbf l'$ in the image is $\mathbf\pi=\mathtt P^T\mathbf l'$. Geometrically, there is a star of planes through the camera center, and the three rows of $\mathtt P$ are a basis for this star. $\mathtt P^T\mathbf l'$ is a linear combination of these basis planes that contains the camera center and $\mathbf l'$. If the world curves—the “rails”—are coplanar, this gives another way to recover them: intersect $\mathbf\pi$ with the ground plane.

For example, let’s take a fairly standard setup of the camera at the origin looking along the $z$-axis toward the image plane $z=1$. For this setup $\mathtt P = [\mathtt I_3\mid 0]$. A line $ax+by+c=0$ in the image back-projects to the world plane $ax+by+cz=0$. If we take $y=-1$ as the ground plane, their intersection is the line $ax+cz-b=0$ in that plane. A straightforward calculation, which I won’t include here, produces $$\mathtt H = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ for the matrix of the homography between these ground and image planes. Using the formula from the top, the line $ax+by+c=0$ in the image then corresponds to the line $\mathtt H^T(a,b,c)^T=(a,c,-b)^T$, i.e., the line $ax+cz-b=0$ as computed previously. The lines $x=\pm h$ therefore correspond to $x=\pm hz$ on the ground. This is a pair of lines that intersect directly below the view point. The angle between them depends of course on their apparent separation in the image.

You raise an interesting follow-up question in various comments: what happens when the view point moves? Moving the camera to $\mathbf t = (t_x,t_y,t_z)^T$ while keeping the camera axis parallel to the $z$-axis and maintaining the same focal distance changes the projection matrix to $\mathtt P' = [\mathtt I_3 \mid -\mathbf t]$. The corresponding homography is $$\mathtt H' = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -t_x \\ 0 & 0 & -(1+t_y) \\ 0 & 1 & -t_z \end{bmatrix}.$$ (As a sanity check, if $\mathbf t = 0$, this reduces to the original $\mathtt H$). Assuming that $t_y\ne1$, which would place the camera on the ground, the ground lines $x=\pm hz$ that gave us parallel lines in the original view are now projected to $$x= {t_x \mp h t_z \over 1+t_y}y \pm h.$$ These lines intersect at the point with homogeneous coordinates $$\left[{t_x \over 1+t_y} : 1 : {t_z \over 1+t_y}\right].$$ These projections of the lines will be parallel when the last coordinate is zero, i.e., when $t_z=0$. So, any movement in $z$—toward or away from the horizon—will destroy the visual parallelism of the lines. If the movement is purely in the $x$-$y$ plane, then the lines will still appear to be parallel, although their slope and separation will change.

Comment: This is interesting but definitely above my head. I don't understand whether this actually explains why the projective lines appear parallel or how to construct those lines (or some other curve that meets the same conditions).

Answer (score 0):

The length separating the rails must be making same angular distance at all lengths from the eye. So let's say the angle is $\theta$ so the distance between the rails at a distance $r$ from the origin (the eye) is $\theta r$. Of course this happens for all $r$ larger than a fixed $r_0$ ( very close to the eye it cannot be kept parallel unless they are infinite distance apart) . So locus of two points having distance  $\theta r$ symmetric about a ray $\theta = \theta_0$. Is the answer in polar coordinates.